# How to reset AWS CLI credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-config, aws-credentials

[image]

I created a user in IAM service. and then I entered AWS configure command and entered user access key and secret key and region correctly. but the default account is not changing according to entered details. after that, I deleted `.aws/credentials` and `aws/config`. Also I reinstalled AWS cli. Without adding any user, still there can be seen default profile with access key, secret key and region.

I entered StackOverflow answer example access keys and secretkeys accidentally using `setx` keyword.

How to solve this problem?

When I give `aws lambda list-functions`, I get this error:

> An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the ListFunctions operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

Comment: Do you just want to enter different credentials? Just run the `aws configure` command again. Anything you enter will overwrite the values.

Comment: but it doesn't overwrite. I tried many times it

Comment: Ah! You used `setx`? This create **Environment Variables**, which will override the settings in the `.aws/credentials` file. You should remove the Environment Variables. [How to Clear Environment Variables in Windows](https://www.alphr.com/clear-environment-variables-windows/)

Comment: I would recommend you to use AWS CLI --profile instead of using default profile

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the **AWS credentials set via Environment Variables** are earlier in the 'credentials provider chain' than the credentials defined in local configuration files.

To use the local configuration files, you will need to 'unset' the Environment Variables.

See: [How to Clear Environment Variables in Windows](https://www.alphr.com/clear-environment-variables-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar issue with aws credentials not being cleared, so I ended up deleting `RegisteredAccounts.json` file in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\AWSToolkit`.

Comment: There is no AppData\Local\AWSToolkit folder on EC2 Windows